# what is the difference between >> and >>> operator in javascript

Tags: javascript

> > ```
> > Signed right shift        5 >> 1   0101 >> 1    0010     2
> > ```
> >
> > `>>>     Zero fill right shift    5 >>> 1   0101 >>> 1   0010     2`
> >     These examples  appear to be same!I want to know difference between these two.

Answer (score 1):

With `>>>`, `0`s are shifted in from the left.

With `>>`, copies of the leftmost bit are shifted in from the left. If the leftmost bit is a 0, it'll be the same as `>>>`, but if the leftmost bit is a 1, it will be different. For example:

```js
// in binary, -5 is represented as 111111111111... on the left
console.log(-5 >> 4);  // -5 >> 4 results in the left side still looking like 111111...
console.log(-5 >>> 4); // -5 >>> 4 shifts in 5 zeros: 000001111111...
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators